# Assembler MMX сумма элементов

Tags: ассемблер

Доброго времени суток. Сижу над простенькой программой на ассемблере, которая должна складывать массивы, но почему-то она складывает лишь первые 2 элемента. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    int array1[5];
    int array2[5];
    int arrayResult[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "array1[" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        std::cin >> array1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "array2[" << i + 1 << "]: ";
        std::cin >> array2[i];
    }

    __asm
    {
        lea EAX, array1
        lea EBX, array2
        movq mm0, [eax]
        movq mm1, [ebx]
        paddb mm1, mm0
        movq [arrayResult], mm1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что ассемблерная вставка выполняется лишь один раз?

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что размер типа `int` в *C/C++* не фиксирован. В 32-битных системах он, скорее всего, будет равен 32-м битам, но стандарт этого не гарантирует. Ассемблерные команды чувствительны к размеру, поэтому лучше использовать типы с гарантированной длиной, например, `int32_t`, размер которого всегда составляет 32 бита.

Далее, используется команда `paddb`. Но она трактует MMX-регистр как совокупность байтов и складывает, соответственно, байты. Из-за этой команды не очень понятно, какого типа должны быть массивы, поскольку объявлены они как `int`, а ассемблер у Вас работает с байтами. Будем считать, что ошибка в ассемблере (как более вероятная) и нужен тип `int`. Тогда складывать нужно четырёхбайтовые целые (`DWORD`) и использовать не `paddb`, а `paddd`.

И, наконец, обрабатывается не весь массив, а только его начало длиной `QWORD`, т.е. два первых элемента. Нужно сделать цикл, просматривающий также и все остальные элементы. Ещё нужно иметь в виду, что MMX-регистр 64-битный, а числа в массиве 32-битные и учесть случай нечётной длины массива. Также было бы неплохо защититься от ошибок в случае массива нулевой длины.

В результате получается следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int32_t dim = 5;
    int32_t array1[dim] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int32_t array2[dim] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int32_t arrayResult[dim] = {};

    __asm {
            lea eax, array1 
            lea ebx, array2
            lea edx, arrayResult
            mov ecx, [dim]
            shr ecx, 1
            jz one

        repeat:
            movq mm0, [eax]
            movq mm1, [ebx]
            paddd mm1, mm0
            movq [edx], mm1
            add eax, 8
            add ebx, 8
            add edx, 8
            loop repeat

            mov ecx, [dim]
            bt ecx, 0

        one:
            jnc end  ; В т.ч. защита от пустого массива

            movd mm0, [eax]
            movd mm1, [ebx]
            paddd mm1, mm0
            movd [edx], mm1
        end:
    }

    for (auto i : arrayResult)
        std::cout << " " << i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Давненько я на asm'е не писал...